# Where did the Generic Text-only printer driver go?

Tags: drivers, printing

I need the generic text-only printer driver but it is no longer available in Ubuntu 23.04, Kubuntu 23.04 and other distros such as Fedora 38. It is still available in KDE Neon and Linux Mint Debian Edition at least.

I had to stop using Ubuntu because of it.

What can I do to have the generic text-only driver back?

PS: There is a driver for my dot-matrix printer but it always prints in graphics mode and it's slow and awful.

Comment: You can select drivers, add/remove/configure printers and print queues by pointing your browser to `http://localhost:631`.

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly the problem: the generic text-only is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use Linux Mint Debian Edition to set up a print queue with the textonly driver.
- A PPD will appear in */etc/cups/ppd*.
- Copy this PPD and use it to set up a print queue on Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will store this PPD file for future installations.